# Bootstrap Fixed NavBar with Spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using two Navbars in my app which collapse individually in smaller screens. 
In Some Screens i will have two NavBars and in some only the top on.

[image]

By adding `navbar-fixed-top` to the navbar it sticks to the top but i want to stack them top of each other and the content of the page should be suitably spaced below so that it has visibility and does not hide below the navbars.

[Link](http://play.mink7.com/noise/noise-html/tasks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the content of your page start below a fixed navbar you need to add a fixed height `padding-top` to the body (see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-navbar-fixed-top-padding). As you have either one or two navbars you'll need two classes with different heights and add one of them to the `body`.

To make the second navbar appear below the first navbar you can add a class like `.navbar-fixed-top--secondary` to it that gets a `top: 50px`.

Comment: thanks i am not able to modify the z-index of the dropdown in the first nav-bar to make it lay over the second navbar. any suggestions?

Comment: Play a bit with the `z-index`, see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/pvrvyY?editors=110 for an example.